# Passing Variable to sed

Tags: unix, sed, parameter-passing

I'm having trouble passing the variable $APN to sed, tried lots of combinations of ' " \ \

First column of .csv files is a number, this code works:

```
cat *.csv > "$APN".csv              #combine

sort -u "$APN".csv -o "$APN".csv    #sort, remove duplicate APNs

sed -i '/^715/!d' combined2.csv     #remove not 715
```

This code third line does nothing:

```
cat *.csv > "$APN".csv             #combine

sort -u "$APN".csv -o "$APN".csv    #sort, remove duplicate APNs

sed -i '/^$APN/!d'                  #remove not $APN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variables inside *single quotes* are not expanded, you need *double quotes*.

```
sed -i "/^$APN/!d" "${APN}.csv"
```

Learn how to quote properly in shell, it's very important :

> "Double quote" every literal that contains spaces/metacharacters and *every* expansion: `"$var"`, `"$(command "$var")"`, `"${array[@]}"`, `"a & b"`. Use `'single quotes'` for code or literal `$'s: 'Costs $5 US'`, `ssh host 'echo "$HOSTNAME"'`. See
>   http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes
>   http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Arguments
>   http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/words

Comment: `!` inside double quotes can cause issue, for example history expansion on bash